# rabbitmq multiple consumer and multiple publisher

Tags: rabbitmq

Want to know the behavior of rabbitmq multiple publisher and consumer.
Does rabbitmq server gives one message to any one of the consumer at a time and other consumers are ideal at that time?

OR

Consumers pick any unattended message from queue, so that at a time, more than one consumers are consuming the message from queue?

Basically I am designing a database queue and do not want more than one inserts at a time.

Answer (score 0):

A message from the queue will be delivered to one consumer only. Ie: once the message makes its way to the queue - it won't be copied (broadcasted) to multiple consumers.

If you want to do broadcast - you have to use multiple queues.

See this tutorial for more details:
   http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorial-two-python.html

Answer (score -1):

yes , RabitMQ supports multiple publisher and consumer.

1. Multiple Publisher

   For publishing a messsge to rabbitmqyou need to declare a factory and do a connection to the rabbitmq server.
   then decare a chennel to rabbitmq

   ```
   ConnectionFactory FACTORY = new ConnectionFactory
   ```

   FACTORY.setUsername ("guest")

   FACTORY.setPassword ("guest")

   FACTORY.setVirtualHost ("\")

   FACTORY.setPort (5572)

   FACTORY.setHost ("localhost")

   Connection connection=FACTORY.newConnection
       Channel channel = connection.createChannel

the basic key to route a message is a routing key

```
channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, "Queue1", MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN, "msg1".getBytes)

channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, "Queue2", MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN, "msg2".getBytes)
```

these two messages will be published to a seperate queue as per the routing key as mention queue1 and queue2

2.Multiple Consumer

for multiple consumer we declare a queue and bind to a particular routing key 
  the the message to that routing key will be publishe to respected queue.

```
  channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "direct", durable)
  channel.queueDeclare("q1", durable, false, false, null)
  channel queueBind ("q1", EXCHANGE_NAME,"queue1")// routing key = "queue1"
  val q1Consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel)
  channel basicConsume ("q1", false, q1Consumer)
```

like this u can consume messages from first queue 
and same goes for second queue but specify the routing key as "queue2"

```
  channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "direct", durable)
      channel.queueDeclare("q2", durable, false, false, null)
      channel queueBind ("q2", EXCHANGE_NAME,"queue2") // routing key = "queue2"
      val q2Consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel)
      channel basicConsume ("q2", false, q2Consumer)
```